# How can I use variables in a Firestore instance

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I need to write a Flutter + Firestore app for three separate divisions and I want to use a variable for the separate Divisions in the database  but the following code fails with

> undefined name 'Division1'.
>   Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name.dart(undefined_identifier)

```
String Division = 'UK';

final CollectionReference usersCollection = Firestore.instance
      .collection(Division)
      .document('2018')
      .collection('Results');
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Can you specify the final code and the exact error

Comment: The code you're showing here doesn't seem to match the error message in any way.  Where is "Division1"? Did you define it?

Comment: Sorry, I tried ({Division1}) but changing the code back I left the 1 off Division (fixed)
ERROR
String Division1

Set literals weren't supported until version 2.2, but this code is required to be able to run on earlier versions.
Try updating the SDK constraints.dart(sdk_version_set_literal)
The argument type 'Set<String>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.dart(argument_type_not_assignable)
Only static members can be accessed in initializers.dart(implicit_this_reference_in_initializer)

Tried pubspec.yaml to   sdk: ">=2.3.0 <3.0.0" still fails. Thank you for replying.